# Moving multiple features on Esri web map at a time?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Is there is any way to make multi-feature movement on Web AppBuilder map?

I am new to Web AppBuilder and I need to do a move on multiple features at a time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "multi feature movement"? Do you mean move the location of multiple features at once?

Comment: Yes, I need to move multiple features on map when a mouse move event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I am not aware of a built-in Web AppBuilder widget that will allow you to move multiple features at a time. You could look into building your own [custom widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/sample-code/create-custom-in-panel-widget.htm).